# How to concatenate array value with another array list value in Python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, concatenation

I am trying to figure out how to append multiple values to a list in Python. I've try for loop and append but i'm really stuck.

Here my list Array:

```
array_1 = [[('Manchester', '23', '80'),
  ('Manchester', '22', '79'),
  ('Manchester', '19', '76')],
 [('Benfica', '26', '77'),
  ('Benfica', '22', '74'),
  ('Benfica', '17', '70')],
 [('Dortmund', '24', '75'),
  ('Dortmund', '18', '74'),
  ('Dortmund', '16', '69')]
]

array_2 = [[('Manchester', '23', 'CM'),
  ('Manchester', '22', 'RM'),
  ('Manchester', '19', 'LB')],
 [('Benfica', '26', 'CF'),
  ('Benfica', '22', 'CDM'),
  ('Benfica', '17', 'RB')],
 [('Dortmund', '24', 'CM'),
  ('Dortmund', '18', 'AM'),
  ('Dortmund', '16', 'LM')]
]
```

I expected the outcome:

```
result = [[('Manchester', '23', '80', 'CM'),
  ('Manchester', '22', '79', 'RM'),
  ('Manchester', '19', '76', 'LB')],
 [('Benfica', '26', '77', 'CF'),
  ('Benfica', '22', '74', 'CDM'),
  ('Benfica', '17', '70', 'RB')],
 [('Dortmund', '24', '75', 'CM'),
  ('Dortmund', '18', '74', 'AM'),
  ('Dortmund', '16', '69', 'LM')]
]
```

i need to save the result into csv with header:

```
club | age | overall | position
```

Comment: your first array is cropped, fix it please

Comment: @YossiLevi sorry, i've fixed

Comment: the output is array_2 .   what is the process you want done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
new_list=[]
for i in zip(array_1, array_2):
    temp=[]
    for k in zip(i[0], i[1]):
        temp.append(k[0]+(k[1][2],))
    new_list.append(temp)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

[[('Manchester', '23', '80', 'CM'), ('Manchester', '22', '79', 'RM'), ('Manchester', '19', '76', 'LB')], [('Benfica', '26', '77', 'CF'), ('Benfica', '22', '74', 'CDM'), ('Benfica', '17', '70', 'RB')], [('Dortmund', '24', '75', 'CM'), ('Dortmund', '18', '74', 'AM'), ('Dortmund', '16', '69', 'LM')]]

Comment: I tried .extend and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the help